# Como obter o primeiro item de um objeto em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho o seguinte objeto em javascript:

```
{
  "tipo_entrega_id" : ["Valor não é válido"],
  "outro_campo"  : ["valor deve ser preenchido"]

}
```

Os valores não são definidor por mim, eles vem dinamicamente através de uma resposta de uma requisição ajax.

Preciso pegar sempre o primeiro valor desse objeto (sem saber qual é a chave) dinamicamente.

Como faço isso em Javascript?

Comment: referes-te a primeiro como quem diz "um qualquer"? ou esperas que essas propriedades tenham uma ordem?

Comment: "um qualquer". Pois o PHP me retorna um erro em json, do jeito que descrevi acima. Daí eu só quero exibir o primeiro mesmo (qualquer primeiro) da lista

Comment: Hmmm... isso não faz muito sentido, para dar uma qualquer, cross-browser, podes fazer assim: https://jsfiddle.net/ov5ym27L/ mas se nõ sabes qual é a primeira qual a utilidade disso para fazer debug?

Comment: @Sergio é porque se a requisição retornar um erro, ele retorna igual o objeto que eu mostrei acima. Qualquer erro que exibir para mim está bom!  Se tudo ocorrer bem, não há erros, então o meu "success" do ajax corre tranquilamente

Comment: _"se a requisição retornar um erro, ele retorna igual o objeto que eu mostrei acima"_ - ele é o servidor, o browser ou uma biblioteca JS?

Comment: @Sergio eu uso o Laravel. O Laravel retorna um JSON (status 422). Daí no   `error`do ajax eu capturo o `error.responseJSON`. Ele vem com o objeto acima, mas eu preciso apenas de uma mensagem de erro, não todas. Como o erro já é automático do sistema, ao invés de mudar tudo que já está pronto, preferi fazer assim nessa parte.

Comment: E porque não escolhes uma das chaves se já sabes a estrutura do objeto, em vêz de "sortear" uma chave?

Comment: @Sergio porque uma hora pode vir uma chave, outra hora pode vir outra. Por exemplo: Se eu tenho os campos "tipo_id" e "observacao", se eu preencher "tipo_id" e esquecer "observacao, vai retornar a chave "observacao" e os erros num `Array`. Se for o contrário, pode vir "tipo_id". Se deixar de preencher os dois,  então virá os dois. É uma validação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método `Object.keys()` retorna um array de propriedades enumeráveis de um determinado objeto, na mesma ordem em que é fornecida por um laço `for...in` (a diferença é que um laço `for-in`  enumera propriedades que estejam na cadeia de protótipos).

**Sintaxe**

> Object.keys(obj)

**Parâmetros**

> obj

O objeto cujas propriedades são enumeráveis.

**Descrição**

**Object.keys()** retorna um array cujo os  elementos são strings correspondentes para a propriedade enumerável encontrada diretamente sobre o objeto. A ordenação das propriedades é a mesma que a dada pelo `loop` sobre as propriedades do objeto manualmente.

**Exemplos**

```js
var obj = {
  "tipo_entrega_id" : ["Valor não é válido"],
  "outro_campo"  : ["valor deve ser preenchido"]

}
console.log(Object.keys(obj)[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer:

```js
var obj = { tipo_entrega_id: 10, outro_campo:123 };
var val1 = obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]; // criar um array com as keys do obj, e depois vamos só buscar a primera, com index 0
console.log(val1); // 10
```

Comment: Bacana, dá pra fazer em "one line"

Comment: De nada, coloquei uma explicação comentada no codigo caso esteja interessado @WallaceMaxters

Comment: Na verdade, você explicou no comentário :-D

Comment: Não funciona  no IE <9

Answer (score 2):

## UnderscoreJS

Se você tem o costume de usar o UndescoreJS, é possível fazer assim:

```
var primeiro = _.first(_.toArray(objeto));
```

Primeiro convertemos o `Object` para `Array` e, em seguida, pegamos o primeiro item com a função `_.first`.

## Javascript Puro

Com javascript, por conta de alguns navegadores não suportarem algumas coisas, você pode usar o `for` e dar um `break` na primeira iteração. Assim você pega o primeiro item.

```
function firstInObject(obj)
{
        for (var key in obj) return obj[key];
}
```